# Как создать график в WPF?

Tags: wpf, диаграммы

Как создать график в WPF с координатами x,y и возможностью создания разных кривых? Я пытался использовать Chart, но я не знаю как создать элемент Chart в коде.

Comment: Кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: Cпасибо всем за ответы

Answer (score 11):

Существует множество библиотек которые позволяют строить различные типы графиков в `WPF` - проектах.

Несколько из них:

- [OxyPlot](http://www.oxyplot.org)
- [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net)

Выбор языка программирования (`F#`) для небольших примеров по использованию оставил на свое усмотрение, так как не было указано явно какой предпочтительнее.

1.
OxyPlot поддерживает различные типы графиков, среди которых `LineSeries`, `PieSeries`, `BarSeries`,...Из недостатков - слабая документация. Проблема существует уже давно, но, к сожалению, работа в этом направлении не ведется. Таким образом найти ответ на интересующий вопрос довольно сложно. Но так как библиотека уже завоевала определенную популярность, то по ней имеется не мало вопросов (с ответами :) ) на английском `SO`, которые должны помочь.

Чтобы ответ был более полным рассмотрим простой пример - построение графиков двух функций `sin` и `cos` с возможностью отмечать галочками отображать обе линии, любую из них или не показывать вовсе.

OxyPlot:

```
xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf"
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <oxy:Plot Title="Пример графика с OxyPlot">
        <oxy:Plot.Series>
            <oxy:LineSeries Title="Cos(x) "
                            ItemsSource="{Binding SPoints}"
                            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=one,
                                                 Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=b2v},
                                                 Path=IsChecked}"
                            Color="Blue" />
            <oxy:LineSeries Title="Sin(x)"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding CPoints}"
                            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=two,
                                                 Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=b2v},
                                                 Path=IsChecked}"
                            Color="Red" />
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
    </oxy:Plot>
    <CheckBox Name="one" Grid.Row="1" Content="Blue" />
    <CheckBox Name="two" Grid.Row="2" Content="Red" />
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel:

```
open OxyPlot
```

...

```
type MainViewModel() = 

    let x = -5.0
    let y = 5.0
    let range = [x..0.1..y] 

    let sindata = 
        range
        |> List.map(fun value -> value, sin value)
        |> List.map(DataPoint)

    let cosdata = 
        range
        |> List.map(fun value -> value, cos value)
        |> List.map(DataPoint)

    member __.SPoints = sindata
    member __.CPoints = cosdata
```

2.
LiveCharts стремительно набирающая популярность библиотека. Из основных преимуществ - документация. Недостатки - баги, которые, впрочем, довольно успешно исправляются. Помимо стандартного набора типов графиков поддерживает `180° Gauge`, `Bubble series`. Кроме этого планируется добавить поддержку некоторых других типов - `Countour Maps`. Если документации будет недостаточно, чтобы найти ответ на вопрос можно написать в чате (`gitter`).

Пример практически аналогичный с предыдущим, только без возможности влиять на отображаемые графики. Связано с тем, что подобным привязка к элементам управления на данный момент не работает. Поэтому нужно создавать свойство в `VM` и связывать с ним.

XAML:

```
xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"


<Grid>
    <lvc:CartesianChart LegendLocation="Right">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:LineSeries PointGeometry="{x:Null}" Fill="Transparent"
                            StrokeThickness="3" Title="Cos"
                            Values="{Binding CPoints}" />
            <lvc:LineSeries PointGeometry="{x:Null}" Fill="Transparent"
                            StrokeThickness="3" Title="Sin"
                            Values="{Binding SPoints}" />
        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
```

VM:

```
open LiveCharts
open LiveCharts.Configurations

type LiveChartsVM() = 
    let x = -5.0
    let y = 5.0
    let range = [x..0.1..y] 

    let sindata = 
        range
        |> List.map(fun value -> value, sin value)
        |> ChartValues

    let cosdata = 
        range
        |> List.map(fun value -> value, cos value)
        |> ChartValues
    do
        let mapper = Mappers.Xy<float * float>().X(fst).Y(snd)

        LiveCharts.Charting.For<float * float>(mapper, SeriesOrientation.Horizontal)

    member __.SPoints = sindata
    member __.CPoints = cosdata
```

Comment: Ого, у нас специалист по F#. Круто!

Comment: @VladD не специалист, но кое-что знаю :)