# Как сделать фиксированый график с реалтайм обновлением?

Tags: c#, wpf, диаграммы, график

Использую стандартные графики c# chart, у меня постоянно динамически добавляются точки, а при добавлении множества точек график сжимается, мне этого не надо, какая настройка отвечает за отключение этой опции?

Легче будет показать пример на JS http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update/dark-unica

Comment: В C# нет не то, что стандартных графиков, а даже стандартной графической библиотеки (т. к. их есть две: WinForms и WPF). О какой реализации графиков идёт речь?

Comment: Графики из WinForms  можно включить в WPF, я про них

Comment: @Fangog, намного проще использовать специальные библиотеки

Comment: ну так это, в Series можно не только добавлять точки но и удалять, там обычная коллекция. Просто при добавлении новой точки удаляйте точку с индексом 0. Если добавляете N точек, то удаляете N точек из начала.

Comment: Да, но график все равно сжимается по горизонтали от момента, когда точек не и до момента когда их, допустим, 10. Я хотел бы убрать это.

Comment: @foggy-finder не нашел ни одной библиотеки которая имела бы нормальный дизайн

Comment: @Fangog, вот, посмотрите тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593060/Как-создать-график-в-wpf/593228#593228

Comment: Для `LiveCharts` даже есть пример в документации: https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Constant%20Changes

Comment: @foggy-finder LiveCharts  очень понравился, оформите как отдельный ответ

Answer (score 0):

Используй вместо листа Queue. И реализуй не меняющийся количество элементов с помощью TrimToSize()

Гугли "FIFO вики" что бы понять логику что такое Queue.

Так же создай метод который обновляет с даного списка точки.

Подпиши даный метод на изменения твоего Queue и будет тебе счастье.

Comment: FIFO - First In, First Out - это общий термин выходящий за рамки программирования. Но в том числе это подхо к реализации некой коллекции. Я написал именно то, что и имел ввиду.

Comment: ну ок, нужно вызывать TrimToSize() при добавлении элемента иль при отрисовке графика. Основная суть ответа не меняется что проще использовать для этих целей Queue, а не List иль Array.

Comment: Я могу сказать что проще написать queue.TrimToSize(15) чем конструкцию из while(list.Count >15) {list.RemoveAt(0);} . ПРОЩЕ и ЧИТАБЕЛЬНЕЕ написать 1 строку чем 4. Неужто не логично? А с аррейом вообще нужно двигать все элементы что бы на начало вставить. Там кода еще больше будет.

Comment: 1. ни ты ни я не знаем там данные появляются по однму элементу или могут появлятся по несколько(AddRange никто не отменял). Потому вайл и только вайл. Иначе график может или поплыть или стать нечитабельным месивом. 2. Не вижу смысла.

Comment: 1. Как я сказал выше: ни ты ни я не знаем как оно там. Соответственно имеет смысл считатся с более общей ситуацией. Если расписывать код под каждое "если", то выйдет черезчур много кода, а то и костылей. Мои варианты как в случае с Queue так и в случае с листом -- расширяемые и менее подвержены ошибкам. Независимо от всяких там "если". Но с Queue код меньше и читабельнее.