# Как в WPF рисовать графики и вывести их в документ?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, график

Требуется сделать десктопное приложение на WPF, делающая расчёты математические, рисующая графики и выплёвывающая отчёт по заданному шаблону. С первым и третьим проблем особо нет.

Проблема только в рисовании графиков функции и как эти графики запихнуть в шаблон (.docx, .pdf).

Есть какие-нибудь библиотеки, статье, встроенные инструменты для .NET/WPF? В Web намного проще было. Не приложу ума, как это сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Practical WPF Charts and Graphics](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430224815)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593060/Как-создать-график-в-wpf/593228

Comment: @maxim должна быть какая-нибудь, может эта подойдет http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/multiple-axes или тут на главной странице гляньте http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/chart.aspx так же можно загрузить демо

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53974/discussion-on-question-by-maxim---wpf-------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пока ответ больше подходит для комментария, но туда не подходит по объему...

Можно использовать `OxyPlot` для построения графика. Пример который набросал за пару минут

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <oxy:Plot Title="Заголовок">
        <oxy:Plot.Series>
            <oxy:LineSeries Title=""
                            ItemsSource="{Binding TestPoints}"
                            Color="Black" />
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:Plot.Axes>
            <oxy:LinearAxis Title="Rx"
                            MajorGridlineStyle="Dash"
                            Position="Bottom" />
            <oxy:LinearAxis Title="Rz"
                            MajorGridlineStyle="Dash"
                            Position="Left" />
        </oxy:Plot.Axes>
    </oxy:Plot>
</Grid>
```

.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static string path = "D://testData.txt";
    public DataPoint[] TestPoints { get; }
        = DataLoader.loadData(path)
           .Select(x => new DataPoint(x.Rx, x.Rz))
           .ToArray();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
public class DataLoader
{
    public static IEnumerable<Data> loadData(string path)
    {
        return
            File.ReadLines(path)
            .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ';' }))
            .Select(x => new Data
            {
                Rx = double.Parse(x[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Rz = double.Parse(x[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            });
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public double Rx { get; set; }
    public double Rz { get; set; }
}
```

Выглядеть это все будет так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<sub>(источник: [nblz.ru](http://0s.ne.on2gcy3l.nfwwo5lsfzrw63i.nblz.ru/WXAv2.jpg))</sub>