# Построение графика в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, graph

Каким образом можно построить график, по типу подобный графику в диспетчере задач Windows?

[image]

Задача решена, вот [один из вариантов возможного решения](https://github.com/SNMetamorph/documentation-examples).

Comment: А почему просто не пользоваться диспетчером, опишите конечную цель

Comment: @0xdb потому что необходимо построить график похожий на график из диспетчера.

Comment: Т. е. оптический похожий, а не по содержанию. Поправте ваш вопрос, чтобы это явно следовало.

Comment: @0xdb да, визуально похожий, поглядел ZedGraph, что-то не нашел пути построения такого графика.

Comment: Вы можете использовать любую библиотеку. Самые простые примеры можете посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593060/Как-создать-график-в-wpf/) . В своих проектах я использую OxyPlot и вам советую. Если будут какие-то вопрос - не стесняйтесь спрашивать ;)

Comment: @FoggyFinder а как называется тип требуемого мне графика? (нет описания осей, значения изменяются в реальном времени)

Comment: @SNMetamorph если не ошибаюсь, то обычный LineSeries, описания осей настраиваются, их можно безболезненно убрать в большинстве случаев, изменение значений в реальном времени тоже на тип графика не влияет

Comment: Проблема в чем? В обновлении данных или настройке визуального оформления?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper в настройке визуального оформления. Пытаюсь убрать шкалу по осям графика, ещё планируется в трекере вместо осей X и Y  вбить свои значения, не называя при этом оси.

Comment: @SNMetamorph какую библиотеку выбрали?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper после поисков всё-таки решил копать OxyPlot, ибо вообще кроме него ничего более-менее ясного не нашел. Сейчас уже практически добился желаемого результата, после решения поставленной задачи выложу код и помечу вопрос решённым.

Comment: есть LiveCharts, там где-то выше в комментариях была ссылка на тривиальные примеры. Окей попробую сегодня тоже пример набросать (для OxyPlot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `OxyPlot`. [Пример](https://github.com/Teren2304/BlockApp) построения графика на `OxyPlot` только нужно разобраться с внешним видом.

Comment: Благодарю, вот [получившийся результат](https://github.com/SNMetamorph/documentation-examples)