# Настройка Chart в WPFToolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, wpf-toolkit

Доброго всем времени суток!

Разрабатываю программу для отображения данных и с нескольких тепловых датчиков. Данные на экран выводятся в виде графика в реальном времени. По оси Y отображается температура, по X - промежуток времени, который прошёл после запуска.

Возникло несколько вопросов:
1. Как сделать, чтобы график не сжимался, а растягивался при добавлении новых точек? Пробовал использовать скролы, но он все равно сжимается, а я хотел бы, чтобы он растягивался дальше. Это дало бы пользователю возможность просмотреть значения, которые были некоторое время назад и не засоряло бы экран.
2. Как изменить стрингформат отображаемых значений по оси Х? Там у меня выводится временной промежуток TimeSpan. При автоматическом выводе запись очень длинная с днями, часами, вплоть до большого количества цифер в милисекундах. Я хотел бы сократить эту запись до часов, минут и секунд.

Буду благодарен за помощью или информацию по данной теме.

Comment: вам обязательно использовать `wpf-toolkit`?

Comment: Для меня обязательно построение графика, а технология, с помощью которой это будет реализовано, не принципиальна.

Comment: тогда вот писал ответ о графиках в `WPF` - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593060/Как-создать-график-в-wpf/

Comment: ооо...читал этот пост ещё до того, как задал вопрос) И раз сам знаменитый VladD отметил вас как хорошего специалиста - ознакомлюсь на досуге с данными библиотеками)

Comment: хм,  даже такие знаменитые люди как VladD иногда ошибаются - к специалистам себя ну никак пока не могу отнести :)

Comment: Полистал документацию на официальном сайте - проект действительно хороший, и выглядит куда лучше хотя и проверенного, но уже устаревшего toolkit'a. Спасибо за рекомендацию, надеюсь за вечер переделаю под него проект!