# Метод реализации графического интерфейса

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, график

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо будет сделать подобную вещь в своей программе на c# Windows Forms, возможно и WPF. Из чего лучше всего сделать такой график? На нем нужно будет и многое другое вырисовывать, но главное это основные свечи(красные, зеленые). Как мысль, самая банальная, сделать координаты и рисовать по ним прямоугольники с линиями сверху и снизу. А при масштабировании вырисовывать другие, более мелкие или большие. Но, может быть, есть более лаконичное решение данной задачи?

Comment: На WPF ну расположите линии и прямоугольники на канвасе, делов-то. Специальных контролов под вашу задачу я не знаю, слишком они специализированные. Впрочем, может быть, есть готовые библиотеки.

Comment: @VladD я вас понял, я думал, что тут должно быть что-то волшебное, а по сути, отрисовка по координатам. Спасибо)

Comment: Магии нет :-) Или грязная работа спрятана в библиотеки, и выглядит как магия.

Comment: @Fresto, Вроде как есть уже готовые решения: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834144/for-wpf-free-candlestick-example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650119/how-to-draw-candle-charts-in-c-sharp

Comment: К сожалению, при текущих правилах so ваш вопрос является оффтопиком: вопрос сформулирован так, что "невозможно дать объективно верный ответ". Библиотек много (их поиск тоже оффтопик, кстати) и какой вариант ответа подойдёт вам больше невозможно определить исходя из формулировки ответа.

Comment: @maxwell может быть и есть готовые, но тут я делаю полностью под себя и поэтому я буду писать всё с 0 сам. Поэтому готовые коды я вряд ли буду использовать) Думал, что именно отрисовка прямоугольников есть в более лаконичном варианте уже с системой координат и т п)

Comment: @AK Да, я не знал, как написать название темы. По сути, мне нужно 1 в 1 нарисовать то, что на картинке, не использую готового. Вот и спросил, каким образом можно это сделать, ну и привел свои мысли по этому поводу, чтобы не казалось, что сам ничего не хочу делать

Comment: Мы понимаем, что вы не халявщик, иначе бы к голосам на закрытие ещё и минусы посыпались. Просто -- ну не формат. Такое можно попробовать в чате спрашивать.

Comment: @AK хорошо, спасибо за объяснения, впредь, постараюсь обдумывать вопросы, прежде чем задавать

Comment: по-моему хороший вопрос, разве что нужно определиться с платформой - WPF или WinForms

Comment: @FoggyFinder WPF в итоге, для разнообразия возможностей. Буду постепенно учиться вырисовывать прямоугольники нужной длины и в нужных координатах. Затем масштабирование и т п.

Comment: [Как создать график в WPF?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593060/Как-создать-график-в-wpf/593228)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш рисунок очень похож на `Candlestick chart`, название которого иногда переводят как [японские свечи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8).

Практически в каждой библиотеки для построения графиков такой тип тоже реализован, поэтому в первую очередь стоит рассмотреть готовые варианты прежде чем изобретать собственный велосипед.

Пример того, как может выглядеть такой график нарисованный при помощи библиотеки [OxyPlot](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подчеркну, что кроме цвета фона использовались настройки по умолчанию, так как не ставил перед собой цели добиться соответствия с приведенным изображением.

Данные получены случайным образом, [по примеру](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/fe84b034c1105fd0cd679d8cedd88d9c20fde417/Source/Examples/ExampleLibrary/Series/FinancialSeries/OldCandleStickSeriesExamples.cs#L33-L37) из репозитория.

Не буду копировать оттуда пример, но переведу его реализацию на F# для более наглядной демонстрации типов и методов библиотеки

```
let candleStickSeries() = 
    let model = PlotModel(Title = "", LegendSymbolLength = 24.0 )
    let s1 = new CandleStickSeries(Title = "", Color = OxyColors.Black)
    let r = Random()

    Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> r.NextDouble())
    |> Seq.scan(fun price a -> price + a + 0.1) 100.0
    |> Seq.indexed
    |> Seq.map
        (fun (i, price) ->
            let high = price + 10.0 + (r.NextDouble() * 10.0)
            let low = price - (10.0 + (r.NextDouble() * 10.0))
            let open' = low + (r.NextDouble() * (high - low))
            let close = low + (r.NextDouble() * (high - low))
            new HighLowItem(float i, high, low, open', close))
    |> Seq.take 30
    |> Seq.iter s1.Items.Add

    model.Series.Add(s1)
    model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis(Position = AxisPosition.Left, MaximumPadding = 0.3, MinimumPadding = 0.3 ))
    model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis(Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, MaximumPadding = 0.03, MinimumPadding = 0.03 ))

    model
```

Если хотите добиться полного (или почти полного совпадения), то советую разбить вопросы на несколько небольших и задать их по метке выбранной библиотеки.